# 2D Array Creations to containing real and imaginary numbers along each axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

This is a simple problem although I'm struggling to find an answer online, mostly due to being unsure as to the best search terms.

Basically, I want to create a 2d array like:

```
[0 + 0j, 1+0j, 2+0j
 0 + 1j, 1+1j, 2+1j
 0 + 2j, 1+2j, 2+2j]
```

I could do this with two nested loops, although I feel there must be a 1 line solution using numpy and arrays?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a = np.arange(3)
>>> a + a[:,np.newaxis] * 1j
array([[ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j,  2.+0.j],
       [ 0.+1.j,  1.+1.j,  2.+1.j],
       [ 0.+2.j,  1.+2.j,  2.+2.j]])
```

Comment: Thanks - this works well! I've chosen it over the other response as by using arrays, I assume it performs better in terms of computational cost.

Comment: @IanRoberts I ran both answers 100000 times, and this one took ~1.07 seconds, while mine took ~0.43 seconds. Operations on this array will probably be faster, though.

Comment: Actually, I just tested `np.array([[a+b*1j for a in range(3)] for b in range(3)])`, converting mine to a NumPy array, and it took ~0.68 seconds (to run 100000 times).

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested list comprehensions:

```
[[a+b*1j for a in range(3)] for b in range(3)]
```

Comment: Thanks, although I assume this should be *1j not j.